# Optimizing a double sum in Julia?

Tags: optimization, julia, time-complexity, numerical-methods

I am trying to find the most efficient way of adding a double sum of the form : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Umhxn.png)

I am currently using a double for loop to code this as so :

```
Gamma_sum1 = 0
Gamma_sum2 = 0
Gamma_sum = 0

for k = 1:(Iterations)
    Gamma_sum1 = u[Iterations + 1 - k]

    Gamma_sum2 = 0
    for j = 1:k
        Gamma_sum2 = Gamma_sum2 + u[j] * u[k + 1 - j]
    end

    Gamma_sum = Gamma_sum + Gamma_sum1 * Gamma_sum2
end

push!(y, Gamma_sum)
```

Unfortunatly, this makes my whole code less efficient by increasing the time complexity of the algorithm by one degree. I was wondering if there was any better method to do this sum with a time complexity of O(n) instead of the (I think) O(n^2) I currently have ? I am not asking to rewrite my code, just looking for a better method to do this double summation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the expression image it seems the sum goes over all 3rd degree terms `u_i u_j u_k` where the indices sum to `m`. This, in the abstract cube of 3rd degree terms, is a plane (diagonal plane cutting the cube) and has O(n^2) elements. Thus, finding a faster algorithm might be tricky. Any more info on the problem or if the calculation is part of a larger one, iterating over `m`s would help.

Comment: A reduction to O(n*log(n)) complexity might be possible through Fourier-transform based convolution algorithms (googling will produce tons of explanations).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an optimized implementation, but it showcases use of FFT to calculate this sum. The complexity is reduced to O(n*log(n)) which for large enough n should be better than original O(n^2). Additionally this showcase requires n to be a power of 2:

```
# unoptimized FFT shamelessly copy-pasted from
# https://github.com/dillondaudert/JuliaFFT/blob/master/julia_fft.jl
# other Julia packages support optimized FFT calculations
function FFT(n::Integer, x::Array{<:Number})
    if n == 1
        return [x[1]]
    end
    evens = [x[2i] for i = 1:n÷2]
    odds = [x[2i-1] for i = 1:n÷2]
    # Since Julia is 1-indexed, we flip the odds and evens at the recursive step
    u = FFT(n÷2, odds)
    v = FFT(n÷2, evens)
    y = zeros(Complex, n)
    for j = 1:n
        τ = exp(2π*im*(j-1)/n) 
        y[j] = u[(j-1)%(n÷2)+1] + τ * v[(j-1)%(n÷2)+1]
    end
    y
end

# O(n*log(n)) implementation of OP calculation
function calc_fft(u)
    n = length(u)
    N = 2*n
    x = vcat(u,zeros(n))
    y = FFT(N,x).^2
    z = FFT(N,y)/N
    return sum([x[i]*real(z[1+((i+n)%N)]) for i=1:n])
end

# original OP implementation
function calc(u)
    Iterations = length(u)
    Gamma_sum1 = 0
    Gamma_sum2 = 0
    Gamma_sum = 0
    for k = 1:(Iterations)
        Gamma_sum1 = u[Iterations + 1 - k]
        Gamma_sum2 = 0
        for j = 1:k
            Gamma_sum2 = Gamma_sum2 + u[j] * u[k + 1 - j]
        end
        Gamma_sum = Gamma_sum + Gamma_sum1 * Gamma_sum2
    end
    return Gamma_sum
end

# some benchmarking prep

using BenchmarkTools
import Random
Random.seed!(12)
u = rand(1024);
```

Benchmark results:

```
julia> @btime calc(u)
  1.267 ms (1 allocation: 16 bytes)
70095.5403921176

julia> @btime calc_fft(u)
  7.755 ms (164893 allocations: 6.34 MiB)
70095.54039211746
```

So, FFT version is slower. But with good FFT implementation, it should be faster even for modest n.
Of course, for truly fast calculation, optimizations like in @AboAmmar answer will also be necessary.

UPDATE:
Testing with `FFTW.jl` package as suggested by OscarSmith gives:

```
julia> v = rand(1024);

julia> @btime calc_fft(v)
  70.352 μs (64 allocations: 196.06 KiB)
64986.609465082154

julia> @btime calc(v)
  1.267 ms (1 allocation: 16 bytes)
64986.60946508216
```

i.e. at n=1024, FFT version is already 10x faster.

And the calculation function is:

```
using FFTW
function calc_fft(u)
    n = length(u)
    N = 2*n
    x = vcat(u,zeros(n))
    y = fft(x).^2
    z = fft(y)/N
    return sum([x[i]*real(z[1+((i+n)%N)]) for i=1:n])
end
```

Comment: how do these timings do with `FFTW`?

Comment: @OscarSmith with `FFTW` the FFT version is already 10x faster at n=1024

Comment: This is interesting, but can you explain a bit the use of the FFT in this context? Besides, there is a multithreaded version of the FFTW. Which one did you use? (it might be even faster in parallel if the current one is sequential). Note that the FFTW do not require data to have a power of two size and it has a complexity of `O(5 n log n)` AFAIK.

Comment: @JérômeRichard , the use of FFT for polynomial multiplication is one of the gems of algorithm world. This comment is too short to explain, but luckily many references. Here is a clear video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h7apO7q16V0 . Why polynomial multiplication? The calculation in the question can be translated into a multiplication of polynomials with the elements of `u` as coefficients. This is more related to math trick going by name of 'generating functions'. Hope this helps.

Comment: You should not use float division followed by integer conversion (`Int(n/2)`). Instead, use proper integer division, `div(n, 2)`. Then you can remove all the `Int` calls.

Comment: Thanks for all the response guys. Once I try implementing and calculating the efficiency of each algorithm, I will approve the most satisfactory algorithm.

Comment: Hey, I just tried to implement your method into my algorithm, but it doesn't support BigFloat variables. Do you know any other kind of FFT algorithm that might do ?

Comment: @RektLzz In the `FastTransforms` package `FastTransforms.GenericFFT.generic_fft(BigFloat[1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0])` works. It would have been helpful to know about `BigFloat` in the question, and for that matter, how big is the vector length N? These details matter for efficiency and make the question and answer better. How many times is the calculation run? Is it run on vectors with dependencies (such as overlapping windows in a signal)?

Comment: Well the length of N can vary, but for real computations it should be around 1000-3000. As for the BigFloat, I use it because I am calculating a N (same N as previously) order taylor series with high accuracy. For the calculations... Well, they are run a lot of times, I would say about 6*(t/h)*(N-2), where h is the time step and t is the time of the simulation and N is the order of the taylor series.

Comment: Okay. For N=1000 to 3000, and BigFloat, FFT should be faster - as related to this question. For the whole simulation, there should be other ways of optimizing, which would probably move away from BigFloat and use problem specific structure. For example, a Taylor series is an approximation in itself, the need to maintain extreme precision using BigFloat on coefficients is excessive - one needs to look at the infleunce of errors on coefficient precision to overall approximation (vs. say increasing degree of expansion). This is getting too long, so maybe rest is for a different question.

Comment: It is one of the only reasonable ways I am going to get high enough accuracy. Here is the paper of the numerical method I am using to give you an idea : https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.6094v2

Comment: @RektLzz Thanks for the reference (I'll have a look). AFAIK a Taylor series has a remainder and a radius from expansion point. These sources of inaccuracy should be compared to precision of coefficients, and the coefficients truncated accordingly. In the least, experimenting with Float32, Float64, Float128 should be done to see influence on precision. I understand chaos induces sensitivity, but sources of errors should be balanced and trade-off with speed should also be considered (reducing/increasing h and t in simulation). Again, further discussion should not be in commnets or this question.

Answer (score 4):

You won't get more than 2X speedup for your double sum. The inner loop can't be removed because different elements are being multiplied in each iteration. The speedup comes from observing that you multiply `n÷2` elements twice in the inner loop. `@fastmath` will also help here.

```
@fastmath function dsum(u)
    m = length(u)
    s = zero(u[1])
    for n = 1:m
        temp = zero(u[1])
        for k = 1:n÷2
            temp += u[k] * u[n-k+1]
        end
        temp += temp + n%2 * u[n÷2+1]^2
        s += u[m-n+1] * temp
    end
    return s
end
```

Testing with a 100-element vector:

```
u = rand(100)
@btime dsum($u)
  1.350 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

UPDATE: using `LoopVectorization` with my optimization can give 10X speedup over original implementation, faster than FFT approach at all `m` except near powers of 2.

```
using LoopVectorization

function dsum(u)
    m = length(u)
    s = u[m] * u[1]^2
    for n = 2:m
        temp = zero(u[1])
        @avx for k = 1:n÷2
            temp += u[k] * u[n-k+1]
        end
        temp += temp + n%2 * u[n÷2+1]^2
        s += u[m-n+1] * temp
    end
    return s
end
```

```
Random.seed!(123)
u = rand(2072)
@btime dsum($u)     # 182.900 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
@btime calc_fft($u) # 456.300 μs (66 allocations: 392.31 KiB)
```

Comment: Hey, just wanted to ask, what do you mean by "at all " m" except near powers of 2 ?

Comment: I mean at all 2^n sizes with n roughly larger than 7, `calc_fft` will most likely be faster. But for all 2^n+1 to near 2^(n+1) `dsum` will be faster. Imagine the performance of fft like a sawtooth curve with peaks at powers of n.